# Is there a Python module to read avro files with pyarrow?

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

I know there is pyarrow.parquet for reading parquet files as arrow table but i'm looking for the equivalent for avro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet there are plans for one, the first step is the [c++ implementation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1209) which hasn't been started yet.